# How do you unsplit terminals in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There is a button to split terminal, there is none to unsplit terminal ?

Comment: As far as I know this is not possible.

Comment: I needed it too a few days ago, not sure why people dislike question. It seems like a pretty new feature, not that heavily used and stabilized yet.

Comment: @Ebuall they don't like each time something is impossible ;)

Comment: If you click on the trash can it will close terminals from right to left

Comment: and 90% of the time I split the terminal by accident. It should be made more difficult to split it.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

click on the sub-terminal (added terminal when you split main terminal) and then click on the trash icon. it will only kill that sub-terminal and leave the main terminal.

Comment: Very helpful. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: I only want to unsplit the terminal and keep both of terminals. how?

Answer (score 15):

### More ways to **unsplit** a split terminal **WITHOUT terminating either terminal** *(Version: 1.64.0)*:

1. Unsplit a split terminal by triggering the **Terminal: Unsplit Terminal** command from the **Command Palette**.

   ref: [VS Code documentation: Integrated Terminal > Managing Terminals > Grouping](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_grouping)
2. From the **Terminal Tabs UI** on the right side of the **Terminal View**, **right-click** the terminal you wish to unsplit, and from the dropdown menu select **Unsplit Terminal**.

Comment: Yup, this works. So glad they added this as a feature in newer versions.

Answer (score 11):

Another alternative is to type `exit` on the terminal you want to close. To switch focus among splitted terminals, you can use <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> / <kbd>right</kbd> arrow, if you prefer not reaching for the mouse.

Answer (score 6):

On Mac, I just need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to kill the current terminal.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to unsplit them but keep them both around and not delete one of them, drag one of the split terminals into the editor area. Then drag it back down into the terminal area. This works for me on VS code 1.58.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

show terminal

[image: 888]

then unsplit terminals

[image: 444]

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + D works on Windows too.